# How can I send a request to Google Chrome images with Java?

Tags: java, android, html, browser, request

I have to enter a word in the input stream, which should then go to Google Chrome images. And return the html containing the page with pictures on the request for this word.
For example. I enter word "cat" to search field and I should get page like this http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=5fe8a4b53719458439387177d0ab6ec8 in html format. That is, my program should work the same way as if I were entering this word in the image search bar in the browser. Or maybe there are the similar ways to do this especially for Android (only java).

Answer (score 1):

Your method doesn’t quite seem the be the correct way to go about doing this and I’d suggest looking into the Google APIs which are available for developers. This page may help you in creating the request to the API endpoint once you find and gain access to the one you need to use - https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request